# Task list doesnt work the same when i separate the css and js into files and link them back to the main html

Tags: javascript, html, css

in this problem my html works fine when everything is all together as seen here https://jualston.github.io/wingit/milestonetest.html  but when i link the src files of the js and the css to the file instead of having too much code in my main html, it doesnt function properly here

-original html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 250px;
}

/* Include the padding and border in an element's total width and height */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Remove margins and padding from the list */
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Style the list items */
 ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  
  /* make the list items unselectable */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Set all odd list items to a different color (zebra-stripes) */
 ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Darker background-color on hover */
ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}

/* Style the close button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the header */
.header {
  background-color: #f4a3dc;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after the header */
.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the input */
input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Style the "Add" button */
.addBtn {
  padding: 50px;
  width: 15%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h2 style="margin:5px">My To Do List</h2>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
  <input type="number" id="myInput1" placeholder="Insert Priority Number (1 being lowest to 3 being highest) ">
  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

<ul id="myUL">

</ul>

<script>
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var inputValue1 = document.getElementById("myInput1").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
     var s = document.createTextNode(inputValue1);
  li.appendChild(t);
  
  if (inputValue1== 1){
 li.style.backgroundColor = "#8cf458";
 
 
  }
  else if (inputValue1==2){
   li.style.backgroundColor = "#faed52";
    
  }
  else if (inputValue1==3){
     li.style.backgroundColor = "#ff5c5c";
  
  }
 if(inputValue1 <1){
 
  alert("Only numbers between 1-3!!");
  }
   if(inputValue1 >3){
 
  alert("Only numbers between 1-3!!");
  }
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

-html with links of respective css and js files

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="todolist.css ">  
<script src="tasklist.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
   <div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h2 style="margin:5px">My To Do List</h2>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Insert task">
  <input type="number" id="myInput1" placeholder="Insert Priority Number (1 being lowest to 3 being highest) ">
  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

<ul id="myUL">
           
</ul>
</body>
<html>
```

-css file

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 250px;
}

/* Include the padding and border in an element's total width and height */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Remove margins and padding from the list */
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Style the list items */
 ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  
  /* make the list items unselectable */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Set all odd list items to a different color (zebra-stripes) */
 ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Darker background-color on hover */
ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}

/* Style the close button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the header */
.header {
  background-color: #f4a3dc;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after the header */
.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the input */
input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Style the "Add" button */
.addBtn {
  padding: 50px;
  width: 15%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

-js file

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (){
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

    // Click on a close button to hide the current list item
    var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
      close[i].onclick = function() {
        var div = this.parentElement;
        div.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    
    // Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
    var list = document.querySelector('ul');
    list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
      if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
      }
    }, false);
    
    // Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
    function newElement() {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
      var inputValue1 = document.getElementById("myInput1").value;
      var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
         var s = document.createTextNode(inputValue1);
      li.appendChild(t);
      
      if (inputValue1== 1){
     li.style.backgroundColor = "#8cf458";
     
     
      }
      else if (inputValue1==2){
       li.style.backgroundColor = "#faed52";
        
      }
      else if (inputValue1==3){
         li.style.backgroundColor = "#ff5c5c";
      
      }
     if(inputValue1 <1){
     
      alert("Only numbers between 1-3!!");
      }
       if(inputValue1 >3){
     
      alert("Only numbers between 1-3!!");
      }
      if (inputValue === '') {
        alert("You must write something!");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
      }
      document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
    
      var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
      var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
      span.className = "close";
      span.appendChild(txt);
      li.appendChild(span);
    
      for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        close[i].onclick = function() {
          var div = this.parentElement;
          div.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

}

Comment: One thing, there's a space after the `.css ` filename in the new link. Other than that, are the new files in the same directory with the html file, or are the new files in subdirectories such as `js` and `css`?  Also, try to clear browser cache to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: 1. Put the `script` tag at the end of the body or add the `defer` attribute. 2. Wrap all your JS code inside a `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {...});`

Comment: @gugadev as in just make that like the head of everything? what i mean is no code added just put that at the beginning with a bracket and close it at the very end of my js code with that bracket? and  for the script tag im confused on the placement where at the end of the body?

Comment: The JS problem is likely **these all code is executing before DOM is loaded**. So, the `querySelector` probably will return `null` for that reason. That's why you need to put your code inside a `DOMContentLoaded` listener, to ensure that code is executed once the DOM is fully loaded. The alternative is use a `defer` attribute in the `script` tag. Why? this attribute tells the browser: "Execute the code of the script when the document has been loaded".

Comment: @gugadev so i tried the adding the DomContentLoaded to the js file and i closed the end of it with bracket but when i went back to my HTML now it submits nothing when i add a task?  and for the defer/script tag github does not allow the js file to have html tags in it i appreciate all the help you can give though im stumped on this problem

Comment: Update your code to test it please.

Comment: it should show the DOM listener now on this page and github @gugadev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the version that works the JavaScript comes after the HTML. This ensures that the JS doesn’t start to run and attempt to reference HTML elements until they are loaded.

In the version that doesn’t work the JavaScript starts loading at the beginning so finds HTML elements aren’t there yet.

Putting the

```
<script src="tasklist.js"></script>
```

at the end, just before the  should solve this.